# how to check content of two directories the same on two servers?

Tags: file, batch-file, server, copy

Suppose there are two servers, A and B. I am at server C. I am copying a lot of files to A and B with the same director, let's say /bb/bin/temp/, but how can I verify that the two copying is conducted successfully and the contents(including the files names and file contents) are exactly the same without no missing files or corrupted contents?

For some reasons, I can't copy the files back from either A or B to C. And A and B can't communicate either.

Answer (score 1):

Use an MD5 checksum and see if they are the same. So, on Server A and Server B, run a checksum for each file received and save the results in a file. Copy the file back to Server C from A and C and see if the checksums match.

You can use `CERTUTIL.EXE` to do that...

```
REM On Server A and B
CERTUTIL -hashfile FILE1 MD5 >  checksums.txt
CERTUTIL -hashfile FILE2 MD5 >> checksums.txt
```

On Server C, retrieve `checksums.txt` from A and B and compare.

Comment: how efficient is that to run for a large number of files? what if the size is also big?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The bigger the files are and the more files there are, the longer it will take - it's a fact of life :-( If you want to know they got there intact, a checksum is the quickest way to tell.